# Sorting Media Library by Author Name

Tags: media-library, sort

When attempting to sort my media library uploads by author's name, it appears that WordPress will only sort by author ID ( http://example.com/wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list&orderby=author&order=desc )

Is this the intended behavior, a bug, or an oversight? It seems pretty useless to sort by author ID, I would much rather sort by first and/or last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Order by the author's display name:

This is most likely by design, because the only information about the author in the `wp_posts` table is the author ID.

We can join it with the `wp_users` table to get more information about the user and then modify the order accordingly.

Here's an example how we can order by the *display name*:

```
/**
 * Modify the author sorting of the media library uploads (mode=list), 
 * use 'display_name' instead of 'post_author'. 
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184501/26350
 */
add_action( 'load-upload.php', function()
{
    add_filter( 'posts_clauses', function( $clauses, $q )
    {
        if(    $q->is_main_query()
            && 'list'   === filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'mode'    )
            && 'author' === filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'orderby' )
        ) {
            global $wpdb;

            // Join part:
            $clauses['join']    .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->users} u 
                ON u.ID = {$wpdb->posts}.post_author ";

            // Orderby part:
            $clauses['orderby'] = str_replace( 
                "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author",
                " u.display_name", 
                $clauses['orderby'] 
            );
        }
        return $clauses;
    }, 10, 2 );
});
```

The *first*- and *last* names are stored in the `wp_usermeta` table, so you would need to adjust the SQL query for that, but note that these fields could both be empty. The *display* name, on the other hand, is always set, afaik.

Comment: I think there is a missing comma on line 19.